# Difference between ShardedJedisPool and JedisPool

Tags: java, redis, sharding, jedis

How are `JedisPool` and `ShardedJedisPool` different? When to use one over the other?

Comment: Use the force, @callow.

Comment: Do you know what sharding is for?